# What is the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I found some sentence in [the online newspaper](http://www.firstnews.co.uk/news/new-flamingo-chicks-arrive-at-chester-zoo-i11106);

> **The Chilean flamingo chicks started to hatch on July 18 with 13 more arriving since then.**

Does it mean some chicks arrived on the 18th and after they arrived 13 more chicks have arrived?

Comment: It seems to imply that, but does not say specifically (I suppose if "started to hatch" means hatched).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence, as it is written, means exactly what you say. However, it seems to me that the sentence is rather clumsy. What it says is that some unknown number of checks arrived, and then 13 more arrived. That's a strange thing to say - one unknown number combined with one highly precise number, which is pointless since we don't know the exact total number of chicks, which would be the interesting number.

I wouldn't be surprised at all if the actual facts were different from what the sentence says, and that the sentence was just clumsily constructed.

Comment: I can easily imagine that information as part of another sentence that was simply left out of the question. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Seaworld](http://seaworld.org/animal-info/animal-infobooks/flamingos/hatching-and-care-of-young/), of all places, Flamingo hatching can take up to 36 hours, making it quite likely that some chicks arrived on the 18th and more followed them afterwards. So yes, your interpretation is probably correct.